# Created a rolling dice in python, but I want the user to be able to input either one out of 2 possible inputs in order to roll the dice

Tags: python

I'm new to coding so apologies for the nooby question. I've written a program that selects a random integer between 2 and 12 (like a pair of 6-sided dice) when the user inputs "r". I want the user to be able to input either a lowercase "r" or an uppercase "R" to achieve the same outcome but I can't figure out how to do it. The same applies to the rest of the code, when the user is asked if they would like to roll again using "y" or "n". Also I think the code as a whole is probably much longer than it needs to be. Please educate me on how to optimise it and get the same results.

```
import random

def roll():
    roll_dice = input("Enter R to roll the dice. Enter X to exit ")
    while roll_dice != "x":
        if roll_dice != "r":
            roll_dice = input("Invalid input. Try again ") 
        else:
            result = random.randint(2,12)
            print(result)
            break
    return result
    

def dice():
    result = roll()
    roll_dice = input("Would you like to roll again? (Y/N) ")
    while roll_dice != "n":
        if roll_dice == "y":
            result = random.randint(2,12)
            print(result)
            roll_dice = input("Would you like to roll again? (Y/N) ")
        else:
           roll_dice = input("That is an invalid answer. Please try again ")
    print("You have finished rolling")


dice()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was composing an answer along with a solution to your issue, I see that similar answers have been posed.  I will still present my suggestion for a solution that parallels previous comments and that is the use of the "lower()" string function.  You can find multiple references to its usage, but here is one that you might reference [String lowercase](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower).

Utilizing this capability within Python following is a possible refactored version of your code.

```
import random

def roll():
    result = 2
    roll_dice = input("Enter R to roll the dice. Enter X to exit ")

    while roll_dice.lower() != "x":
        if roll_dice.lower() != "r":
            roll_dice = input("Invalid input. Try again ") 
        else:
            result = random.randint(2,12)
            print(result)
            break
    return result
    
def dice():
    result = roll()
    roll_dice = input("Would you like to roll again? (Y/N) ")
    while roll_dice.lower() != "n":
        if roll_dice.lower() == "y":
            result = random.randint(2,12)
            print(result)
            roll_dice = input("Would you like to roll again? (Y/N) ")
        else:
           roll_dice = input("That is an invalid answer. Please try again ")
    print("You have finished rolling")

dice()
```

Testing this refactored code produced the following test results at the terminal.

```
@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Dice$ python3 Roll.py 
Enter R to roll the dice. Enter X to exit r
11
Would you like to roll again? (Y/N) y
6
Would you like to roll again? (Y/N) n
You have finished rolling
```

All of the answers are constructive and should assist you.  See if this refactored code meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: thankyou, this is really helpful. Can you help me understand why you had to assign the `result` variable inside of the `roll()` function?

Comment: Oh.  I did that because when I did an initial test without that new line of code, immediately inputting "x" executed the return result statement which caused an error stating "result" was not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for multiple conditions in the if statement:

```py
if roll_dice != "r" and roll_dice != "R":
```

or you can convert the input to lowercase:

```py
roll_dice = input("Enter R to roll the dice. Enter X to exit ")
roll_dice = roll_dice.lower()
```

As for tips to improve the code, I would suggest the following:

1. Use descriptive names so you can immediately see what something is/does without looking at the logic. For example, split the if statement and the condition by first giving the condition a descriptive name.
2. Keep functions compact. They should really just do one thing.
3. Try not to use `else` when having an `if` statement to prevent nesting of logic.

For example:

```py
import random

def get_dice_roll_results(number_of_dice=1, number_of_faces=6):
    roll_results = []
    for index in range(number_of_dice):
        roll_results.append(random.randint(1, number_of_faces))
        
    return roll_results
    
def run():
    total_roll_count = 0
    
    while True:
        query = "Would you like to roll the dice? (y/n)\n"
        
        is_rolling_again = total_roll_count > 0
        if is_rolling_again:
            query = "\nWould you like to roll the dice again? (y/n)\n"
            
        input_value = input(query).lower()
        answer_is_invalid = input_value != "y" and input_value != "n"
        
        if answer_is_invalid:
            print("That is an invalid answer. Please try again.")
            continue
        
        should_role_dice = input_value.lower() == "y"
        
        if not should_role_dice:
            break
        
        roll_results = get_dice_roll_results(2, 6)
        total_roll_count+=1
        
        result_template = "You rolled ({individual_dice}) totalling {total}!"
        formatted_result = result_template.format(
            total=sum(roll_results),
            individual_dice=", ".join(str(roll) for roll in roll_results)
        )
        
        print(formatted_result)
    
    print("\nYou have finished rolling!")

run()
```

Comment: As for tips to improve the code, I wouldn't worry about it too much. If you're new to coding, just have fun. Also, I kind of like longer code as it is usually more readable.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I don't know why i didn't think of using "and". I was trying to use "or" to no avail.

Comment: @lukimari444 I expanded the answer a little bit with some tips. I hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

use some condition checking

```
if roll_dice != "r" and roll_dice != "R":
```